# Folder redirection save times are awful slow

Tags: windows-server-2008, folder-redirection

I recently set up folder redirection for Documents on Server 2008, but it's painfully slow at the moment. My users are all using Visual Studio 2010, and a save takes 20-30 seconds (whereas it used to take 2 seconds locally).

I understand this is because they are being saved to the server, and that takes time (though I did think it would be faster over a gigabit link, with servers on the same network). I enabled offline files on the share, set the option to All files or folders, and enabled Optimize for performance. I thought that this would pull all the files down locally (which I think it did), allow local editing of said files, synchronizing them quietly in the background from time to time (which it does not do - saves right to the share).

Is there any way I can speed this process up a bit? Any other tweaks I can do?

Comment: Is regular access to a fileshare on that server slow as well?

Comment: I once ran into Folder Redirection problems due to A/V. Similar to what you describing

Answer (score 1):

Did you just setup the document redirection? It might still be in the process of redirecting all of the documents for member machines which the group policy is applied to.

depending how many machines you have that will be performing this it can give a pretty good outline as to how long it might take.  if users are trying to redirect while the server is still trying to sync all of the documents locally on every machine that is in place there is going to be a lot of transferring of files going on for the time being.  usually what i found helps with introducing redirection for the first time is separating machines and users by OUs and deploying this policy to just a few machines at a time.

if everything is already in place and its just simply slow going forward and you have mentioned you have gigabit connectivity, take a look at the storage on the file server which is storing all of these documents.  look at the disk queue length and what is the raid configuration? it may not have enough I/o..

Comment: No, it's already synced the files - the delay occurs on save, every save. Policy is presently on about 3 users, all of which were synced a few days ago. I'll take a look at the disk queue length, though it should be minimal since only three of us are even touching the machine. No RAID, server is running in a VM cloud.